# Jquery prevent multiple submit

Tags: jquery

I want to prevent multiple submit if someone click on one of the submit buttons multiple times.

How can `unbind` or `undelgate` in this case the call of my custom function `do_some_stuff` that is only happens one time, because I try some of the jquery methods, but I think I did something wrong. Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $('div.ajax').delegate('form button', 'click', function(e) {
        $(this).do_some_stuff();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Bind and unbind are deprecated in JQuery.

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

To answer your question about multiple submits, another new addition in JQuery 1.7 is the `.one()` handler which, attaches an event handler to an object but only allows it to be fired once.  This will allow you to prevent multiple submits.

e.g:

```
$("form#form1").one("submit", submitFormFunction);

function submitFormFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("form#form1").submit();
}
```

Note I'm binding to the form submit event rather than a button click event.

Comment: Thanks this handler just saved my bacon and my sanity :-)

Comment: Just a slight spello, your example uses .one() not .on()

Comment: @GDW: That's not a typo or a "spello" (cool word btw :)).  [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) attaches an event handler that will only fire once.   It's the whole point of that part of the answer.

Comment: That part does seem a bit...odd, though.  To me it looks like it'd submit every time regardless.  (Once the handler submits the form, and is detached, nothing's preventing the default action anymore.)  Seems like you'd also need to attach a more persistent handler that always prevents the default action.

Comment: .one doesn't seem to be working as intended.
Let's say that you have a confirm() message in the submitFormFunction, meaning you only execute the code if the user choses affirmatively.
The first time you execute the method that message appears but, if you cancel and submit again, that submitFormFunction is not getting executed on the second time.
Instead the form is simply submited without calling the event.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of doing this as pointed out by cHao.

```
$('form button').prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$('form button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: This should be `.prop('disabled', true)` or `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` if you care about doing things correctly.

Answer (score 3):

when you click the button within the function add the attr(disabled) which will make the button inactive.

```
$("form Button").attr("disabled","1");
```

should prevent multiple submissions

Comment: If you use `.attr`, you should set the value to `'disabled'` rather than 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you have users who insist on having an active submit button all the time you can use a variable to track the progress. Something like this:

```
saving_record = 0; //set variable to show if form is in submission
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        if (saving_record === 0) { //If not submitted yet, submit form
            saving_record = 1; //Set variable to show form is in submission
            $.ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    saving_record = 0; //Reset variable to allow record update
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    saving_record = 0; //Reset variable to allow record update in case of error
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations for Client side Validation, you have to validate the form first -

```
// To prevent multiple post
function buttonsubmit() {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($('form').valid()) {
            $(this).find("input[type='submit']").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
$(".button").on("click", (el) => {
    if (el.detail !== 1) { return; }

    // rest of your code here
});
```

`el.detail` contains the click count. Anything > 1 will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div.ajax form').submit(function(){
     $(this).do_some_stuff();
     return false;
   });          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on submit

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    // submit more than once return false
    $(this).submit(function() {
        return false;
    });
    // submit once return true
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The one() event did not prevent multiple submits in my case.

This code was used instead:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (ev) {
        $("#SaveAndQuit").on('click', function (ev) {             
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');

            if ($form.valid()) {
                
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);

                // (optional: if multiple submit button, specify which one has been cliqued to the MVC controler)
                $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="SaveButton" value="SaveAndQuit" /> ');

                $form.submit();
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

(Visual studio 2017, MVC project, Jquery 3.1.1)