# Disable Additional Clicking During Page Load/Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to prevent multiple clicks on a submit button from being registered. Currently I am using jQuery's .one() function, which does prevent additional clicks from being registered (as far as I can tell through console logs, anyway), but I'm noticing two things: First, the button can still be clicked multiple times, which restarts the load. Second, clicking any other button and then clicking back will treat it as a second click.

How do I fully prevent any other clicks during the submit without potentially interfering with the submit itself?

Answer (score 0):

On your event use the jQuery function "off(event)" and when you processing is done turn back handler...

```
function _on_click_event_handler(e) {
  // on your event, turn off event(s)
  $button_control.off("click");

  // processing ....

  // when your processing is done, assign back handler for this event
  $button_control.click(_on_click_event_handler);
}
```

Comment: So as mentioned I'm currently using $("#button").one('submit', function() {...}). Would your suggestion be compatible with that?

Sorry, not a whole lot of experience with event handlers. ^_^;

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Jquery prevent multiple submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719376/jquery-prevent-multiple-submit) I don't want to copy and paste the examples already provided in the resource.